# How to rewrite some values in query? - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got a query which result is in `table1`

```
-------------------------
|column1|column2|column3|
-------------------------
|   v1  |   30  |  40   |
|   v1  |   34  |  41   |
|   v1  |   35  |  42   |
|   v2  |   30  |  40   |
|   v2  |   34  |  41   |
|   v2  |   35  |  42   |
-------------------------
```

I want to change duplicated values to `NULL` in first column, (i.e).

```
-------------------------
|column1|column2|column3|
-------------------------
|   v1  |   30  |  40   |
| null  |   34  |  41   |
| null  |   35  |  42   |
|   v2  |   30  |  40   |
| null  |   34  |  41   |
| null  |   35  |  42   |
-------------------------
```

What should I do with table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) > 1 
             then null else col1 end) col1, 
        col2, col3
from table t;
```

However, you can also use `lag()` function

```
select (case when lag(col1) over (partition by col1 order by col1) = col1 
                  then null else col1 end) col1, 
        col2, col3
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN D.RN = 1 THEN column1 ELSE NULL END AS column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
FROM(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1)RN
    FROM Your_table
    )D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

using `ROW_NUMBER` function to make rowNumber,then `CASE When` Expression to show the first `column1` else be null

`ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` can let your data be the original order.

```
select CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN  column1 ELSE NULL END,
       column2,
       column3
from 
(
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn 
  FROM T
) t
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcf3d/1*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN
          "column1"
       ELSE
          NULL
       END AS "column1",
       "column2", "column3"
FROM
(
SELECT 
"column1", "column2", "column3",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY "column1" ORDER BY "column1") AS RN
FROM Table1
) AS T
```

**Ouput**

```
column1 column2 column3
v1      30      40
(null)  34      41
(null)  35      42
v2      30      40
(null)  34      41
(null)  35      42
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5b2e1/9